# Create new Git branch from existing files

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I recently installed git on development server. It's great so far. But...

The problem now is that the production server diverged from development at some point in the past, before the earliest version of the "master" branch on the development. For example, hot fixes were applied in production that weren't applied on the development site, and certain improvements or tweaks or even just comments were made in code on development but not in production.

So what I'm thinking to do is to make the production files a branch off of master, say "legacy", and pull that branch down to my development machine and visualize the differences. I expect to merge most changes in "legacy" into "master," but probably not all. And I expect little conflict bewtween the changes in my other development branches and "legacy".

I haven't found anything on this subject on Google yet, possibly because I'm not using the right search terms. Any hints?

Comment: Could it be this simple? Create a branch from master, dump your production files on top of it (literally copy them into the code directory), then use your diff tool to see what's changed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). You can pick and choose which commits, either individually or in a range, to apply to your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

1) Checkout a new "Legacy" branch from Master

2) Dump your production files on top of it and commit

Now you have two branches (Master and Legacy) and you can diff, merge, etc.

Comment: This is something I was thinking of trying. Does git care if all the files have different dates now, or does it only look at file contents/names?

Comment: @ButtleButkus dates are ignored, only content/name is relevant for git